# Blank page when accessing shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shopping-cart

When logged in and trying to view the shoppingcart (not empty) I get a blank page.

This is what the system.log shows:

```
2015-04-28T14:15:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:14+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:15:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:19:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2015-04-28T14:19:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2015-04-28T14:19:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100
2015-04-28T14:19:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2015-04-28T14:19:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2015-04-28T14:19:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100
2015-04-28T14:19:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:19:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:19:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:20:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:20:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:20:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:21:39+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:21:39+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-04-28T14:21:39+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lida/domains/etk.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I have not made any changes that could generate this.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that you are missing the file `app/code/codeMage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Result/Error.php` or it may not be readable.
Get it from a clean magento instance.